# Is there any way to show less decimals than the specified accuracy in Odoo 8 views?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, floating-accuracy

I am trying to manage the following behaviour in Odoo 8:

Set a product price of 5 decimals. For that, I set decimal accuracy of Product Price to 5.

In `sale.order` view, show only 3 decimals, but calculate the subtotal of the line taking into account the 5 decimals. For this step, I am modifying the view to put this on `price_unit` field:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="replace">
    <field name="price_unit" digits="(16,3)"/>
</xpath>
```

But that `digits` attribute is altering the result.

> Example:
>
> I store a product with price 1,00123. I add 5 units of it on a sale
>   order. If I do not use `digits` in the XML view, the subtotal is 5,01.
>   Because 1,00123 * 5 = 5,00615, rounding this to Account Accuracy (2
>   decimals) gives 5,01. But if I use digits in XML view, the subtotal is
>   5,00. Because 1,001 * 5 = 5,005, rounding this to Account Accuracy (2
>   decimals) gives 5,00.
>
> In fact, I show with logger the `line.price_unit` value in
>   `sale.order.line` method `_calc_line_base_price`. With digits in XML
>   view, `line.price_unit` values 1,001, without it, it gives 1,00123.

Can anyone tell me how could I show 3 decimals for price unit in XML
view without altering the decimal accuracy of 5 decimals? It must be
done only for visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the xml `digits` are indeed taken into account for calculations (can't verify that at the moment), you can always have two fields - hidden one for calculations with maximum accuracy, and another for display purposes, which displays already calculated numbers with specified accuracy.

Comment: It seems to be the only way to manage the purpose. Thank you!